# Trying to use C# DLL with ComVisible attribute set from unmanaged C++

Tags: com, com-interop

TL;DR: I'm trying to use a C# library in C++. Why am I getting an undeclared identifier error when trying to use an identifier from my .tlh file?  There must be tons of examples out there, but I haven't been able to find any that include both the C# and C++ code, and that work.  Links to such examples would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following classes defined in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace CapsCrystalReportLib
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("B4E5F784-12E6-4311-9BB9-D5B3252F20A3")]
    public interface ICapsCrystalReport
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void DisplayReport(string fileName);
        [DispId(2)]
        void PrintReport(string fileName);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("89402DE5-BA26-4AC0-AB40-00ADD2876FF4")]
    [ProgId("CAPSCrystalReport.Report")]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ICapsCrystalReport))]
    public class CapsCrystalReport : ICapsCrystalReport
    {

        public void DisplayReport(string fileName)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Displaying report " + fileName);
        }

        public void PrintReport(string fileName)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Printing report " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following C++ program attempting to use this class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "W:\\CAPS Builds\\trunk\\CapsCrystalReportLib\\bin\\Debug\\CapsCrystalReportLib.tlb" no_namespace

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   // Initialize COM.
   HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

   // Create the interface pointer.
   CapsCrystalReport CRPtr(__uuidof(CapsCrystalReport));

   long lResult = 0;

   // Call the Add method.
   CRPtr->DisplayReport("SomeReport.rpt");

   // Uninitialize COM.
   CoUninitialize();

   return 0;

}
```

I am getting an undeclared identifier error. The compiler doesn't know what a CapsCrystalReport is. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I took another look at the sample I copied this from. One of the comments asks the same question, and it was never answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, but CRPtr is a COM interface reference (=pointer) so it must be declared like this:

```
ICapsCrystalReportPtr CRPtr(__uuidof(CapsCrystalReport));
```

The IxxxPtr class was generated for you by #import in a .tlh file. What you can do when you have issues with #import, is just open the generated .tlh file and look at it.

Note you don't have to declare a default interface in C#, you can just declare the class like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("89402DE5-BA26-4AC0-AB40-00ADD2876FF4")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("CAPSCrystalReport.Report")]
public class CapsCrystalReport
{
    ... same ...
}
```

And in C++, you would have to adapt your imports like this:

```
#import "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb" auto_rename
#import "W:\\CAPS Builds\\trunk\\CapsCrystalReportLib\\bin\\Debug\\CapsCrystalReportLib.tlb" no_namespace
```

and you would use it like that (the interface was implicitely created by .NET and wrapped by the #import):

```
_CapsCrystalReportPtr CRPtr(__uuidof(CapsCrystalReport));
```

PS: I would recommend you to keep the namespace, avoid `no_namespace` because it can cause problems with collisions especially in C++.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That worked when using ICapsCrystalReportPtr.

You mention _CapsCrystalReportPtr at the end.  I tried using that, but it didn't work, throwing an E_POINTER error when it tried to call DisplayReport().  Why would I use _CapsCrystalReportPtr, and what would I have to change to get it to work?

Comment: _CapsCrystalReport is an interface that's built automatically by .NET and #import if you use a C# code like mine. E_POINTER means the pointer is null, so the COM interface was not created successfully, it's probably a guid mistmatch between the class and the interface it supports. IBlablaPtr ptr(__uuidof(Blabla)); will set null to ptr if Blabla class exists but doesn't implement IBlabla. But you can keep your code as is (IMHO it's just painful to have to create an extra interface)